# Distribute multiple versions of an app

Tags: ios, crashlytics-beta

Using *Crashlytics Beta*, is there a way to deploy multiple versions of my app to a phone? 
This would be useful so we can have one version for our 'stable' branch and one for our 'dev' branch.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to have multiple version of an app at the same time on a single device is to have different bundle id.

Like `com.site.myapp` for stable and `com.site.myapp.dev` for the test version. THe when passing to stable, you update the bundle id.

Not pretty confortable but didn't found any other solution.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is possible. From Crashlytics Support team:

> If you're using the same bundle id, then create a new organization within Crashlytics, and change the API key and build secret depending on the version that you're building. We group apps based on the API key, platform, and bundle id, so having different API keys will do the trick for you :)

I'm yet to try this so can't confirm that it works.

Comment: Crashlytics organization has nothing to do with iOS. You will not be able to install two different apps (or two versions of the same app) in the same time.